# trying to move robot using the distance from camera to face

Tags: python, arduino, serial-port, raspberry-pi3, arduino-c++

So, i am  trying to move a dc motor using the distance from my face to a raspberry camera.
I have the raspberry connected to an arduino mega via serial comunication.
Currently i am testing only one dc motor.
I should say that i am using an raspberry pi 3b+ with 1 gb of ram.
This is the raspberry pi code:

```
`import numpy as np
import cv2 

USB_PORT = "/dev/ttyUSB0"  # Arduino Uno WiFi Rev2
# Imports
import serial

try:
   usb = serial.Serial(USB_PORT, 9600, timeout=2)
except:
   print("ERROR - Could not open USB serial port.  Please check your port name and permissions.")
   print("Exiting program.")
   exit()

Known_distance = 76.2

Known_width = 14.3


GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
RED = (0, 0, 255)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)


fonts = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX

face_detector = cv2.CascadeClassifier("haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")

def Focal_Length_Finder(measured_distance, real_width, width_in_rf_image):

    
    focal_length = (width_in_rf_image * measured_distance) / real_width
    return focal_length


def Distance_finder(Focal_Length, real_face_width, face_width_in_frame):

    distance = (real_face_width * Focal_Length)/face_width_in_frame

    
    return distance


def face_data(image):

    face_width = 0 

    
    gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    faces = face_detector.detectMultiScale(gray_image, 1.3, 5)

    for (x, y, h, w) in faces:

        cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), GREEN, 2)

        face_width = w


    return face_width


ref_image = cv2.imread("Ref_image.png")


ref_image_face_width = face_data(ref_image)

Focal_length_found = Focal_Length_Finder(
    Known_distance, Known_width, ref_image_face_width)




cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
if not cap.isOpened():
    print("Cannot open camera")
    exit()
while True:
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    # if frame is read correctly ret is True
    if not ret:
        print("Can't receive frame (stream end?). Exiting ...")
        break
    # Our operations on the frame come here
    face_width_in_frame = face_data(frame)

    if face_width_in_frame != 0:
        Distance = Distance_finder(Focal_length_found, Known_width, face_width_in_frame)
        cv2.line(frame,(30,30),(230,30),RED,32)
        cv2.line(frame, (30, 30), (230, 30), BLACK, 28)
        cv2.putText(
            frame, f"Distance: {round(Distance,2)} CM", (30, 35),
        fonts, 0.6, GREEN, 2)

        if(Distance<50 ):
            print("back")
        elif(50<Distance<80):
            print("stop")
            usb.write(b'of') 
        elif(Distance>80):
            print("forward")
            usb.write(b'on')


    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break
# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()

cv2.destroyAllWindows()`
```

and the arduino code is this:

```
`#include <AFMotor.h>

AF_DCMotor motor(1);

void setup() {
  //mstop();
  Serial.begin(9600);

}

void loop() {
   if (Serial.available()) {  // check for incoming serial data
      String command = Serial.readString();
      if (command == "on"){
        forward();
      }else if(command=="of"){
       mstop();
      }}

}

void forward(){
  motor.setSpeed(200);
  motor.run(FORWARD);
}

void mstop(){
  motor.run(RELEASE);
}`
```

So, the problem is that when i run the python code it's working till the if statements, those one :

```
        `if(Distance<50 ):
            print("back")
        elif(50<Distance<80):
            print("stop")
            usb.write(b'of') 
        elif(Distance>80):
            print("forward")
            usb.write(b'on')`
```

and i know that the print statements work just fine, but the `usb.write(b'of')`  and  `usb.write(b'on')` parts are only working sometimes.
I want them to send info to the arduino smoothly to the arduino, i tried using the sleep function but it won' t work.

I am expecting to start and to stop the motor based on the distance from the camera to my face, and to do this smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

Try using 1 character like '1' or '0' (use single quote instead of double,  Serial.read() in arduino instead of Serial.readString(), and char instead of String.

```
char command = Serial.read();
if (command == '1') {
```

Then usb.write(b'1') and usb.write(b'0') in Python

From my past experience, I had arduino readString()s like "on " instead of "on"